# Python: Request large payload from URL

Tags: python, url, python-requests, http-headers, large-data

I am trying to get data from a URL using Python. The code I am using is this:

```
response = requests.get(
                url="https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/"+Chain_id+"/address/"+Address+"/transactions_v2/?    key=API_KEY",
            headers={
                "Authorization": "Basic AUTHORIZATION",
            },
        )
result = response.json()
result = result['data']['items']
```

So I am entering a Chain_id and wallet address in the URL to get all the transactions for that pair. However, I only get the latest 100 transactions at most. Is there a way to get all transactions? Is there a parameter I can add to `requests` to get all the data points?

For example, putting this wallet address, 0x60b86AF869f23aEb552fB7F3CaBD11B829f6Ab2F, into etherscan.io (https://etherscan.io/address/0x60b86af869f23aeb552fb7f3cabd11b829f6ab2f), you can see that there are over 51000 transactions however I only get the latest 100.

Comment: You can try to request with additional param `page-number`, and _paginate_ it, meaning to construct a loop to loop through "pages" of data, with each time getting 100 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rodrigo-cava said, you can retrive 100 items (default value) for request.
This means that you have to fetch the page in order to collect all the result.

A solution may be the following:

```
CHAIN_ID = "your chain id"
ADDRESS = "your address"
API_KEY = "your api key"

response_list = list()   

url = f"https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/{CHAIN_ID}/address/{ADDRESS}/transactions_v2/?key={API_KEY}"
response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic AUTHORIZATION"}).json()

while response["pagination"]["has_more"]:
    page_number = response["pagination"]["page_number"] + 1
    url = f"https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/{CHAIN_ID}/address/{ADDRESS}/transactions_v2/?page-number={page_number}&page-size=100&key={API_KEY}"

    response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Basic AUTHORIZATION"})
    if not response.ok:
        raise Exception("Error during the request")
    
    response_list.append(response.json())
```

Comment: I am trying this but it gives me the following error: `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable` specifically at ( while response["pagination"]["has_more"]:)

Comment: have you invoked the `.json()` method after the request? the error seems to point that  `response` is a `requests.Response` object instead of a json

Comment: I entered exactly what you have with the appropriate chain id, address, and api key and I get `KeyError: 'pagination'`. Not sure why it's a key error though

Comment: Can you check in the console what are the keys of the response object? Looks like that this field does not exists. I've tried in the official [website](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#/0/Get%20transactions%20for%20address/USD/1) and I found that there is a 'pagination' key.

Comment: When I print the first response I get this back `{'data': {'address': 'ADDRESS', 'updated_at': '2022-04-27T23:37:41.308110330Z', 'next_update_at': '2022-04-27T23:42:41.308110710Z', 'quote_currency': 'USD', 'chain_id': 1, 'items': [], 'pagination': None}, 'error': False, 'error_message': None, 'error_code': None}`

Comment: I'll check. (PS: remove the address!)

Comment: I have updated my answer; let me know if it is ok

Comment: I see where the issue arises now. "pagination" is a subset of "data" so the answer should be response['data']['pagination'][...] I think. But this format results in `TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable` I am trying to resolve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244300/discussion-between-mathman-99-and-sprizgola).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with `requests`, it's a limitation from the API itself.

Looking into the [API docs](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#/0/0/USD/1) they say they have a limit of 100 request per page.

[image]